# How to start with HTML5 (or at least "browser based") E-Reader

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've to develop an web-based E-Reader for Newspapers. I looked around the Internet for good tutorials, but didn't really found what I was looking for. I already scaled down my (and everyone else's) expectations to have an good entry point to start from:
All I want (at first) is an image viewer showing all images/news pages as thumbs and the selected page in a big view. Navigation should be possible via thumbs and next/prev buttons.
Do give an idea I attached a sketch below.
[image: E-Reader Sketch]

Best thing I found was Apple's HTML5-Sample ["Photo Gallery"](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/CSSEffectsPhotoGallery/Introduction/Intro.html), which unfortunately only works with webkit browsers.

Any ideas for good sample code/tutorials to start from?

Comment: What will be in your thumbs ? AFAICT there's not one (the page reduced to a thumb ? a random image on the page, like when you share a link on facebook ?). Also, is it something like that : alt-tab.org ? In what your question is related to html5 ? I'm sorry I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be the code you will support later - then if I were you, i would write my own.

I did this task before, but can not share, since it is private.

Pay attention to the next issues, you will probably meet

1. image showing in canvas
2. zoom in/out in a canvas
3. pre-load images/pages/resources for the better performance, but not overuse the memory
4. delete old nodes after they are not used
5. if one of the target browsers is IE - pay additional attention to it, because it can turn into hell. IE6 uses near neightbour interpolation by default - it makes text unreadable.

Probably it does not answer your question directly, but probably gives the vision of low-level problem set.

Answer (score 1):

This should be relatively easy, almost any jQuery/Javascript slideshow tutorial online could be adapted to work like you need it. Is your eReader pages going to be text/images, or just a plain image?

Comment: For the start it will be plain images.

Comment: Even better. Just google "javascript slideshow thumbnail tutorial" online.

Answer (score 1):

You can find lots of "slide show" and "photo gallery" examples to include in your own design. Just google for `css image gallery slideshow` and you'll find one that fits your needs.

A good looking example for a photo gallery is http://flash-gallery.com/art-flash-gallery/

And if you use http://www.shadowbox-js.com/ you can scroll flip through a collection of web pages, not just images.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://www.ted.com/talks/mike_matas.html for some nice ideas